# How to solve this and get 5/42 as the answer?

Tags: probability

An urn contains 10 balls numbered 1 through 10. Five balls are drawn at random and without
replacement. Let A be the event that “Exactly two odd-numbered balls are drawn and they occur on
odd-numbered draws from the urn.” What is the probability of event A?

And the answer is given as 5/42

How to obtain it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, note that there are $10\cdot 9\cdot 8\cdot 7\cdot 6 = 30240$ ways to draw sequences of balls from the urn.

We wish to enumerate the number of ways to choose $2$ odd-numbered balls on odd-numbered draws. First, there are $\binom{3}{2} = 3$ ways to choose the draws on which the odd numbers will occur. Next, there are $5\cdot 4 = 20$ ways to choose the odd numbers which will be drawn. Finally, there are $5\cdot 4\cdot 3 = 60$ ways to choose the even numbers which will be drawn.

Thus, the desired probability is $\frac{3\cdot 20\cdot 60}{30240}$, and reducing, we obtain an answer of $\boxed{\Pr(A) = \frac{5}{42}.}$

Comment: Do you think that the OP should show work before being given an answer?  If not, what is the point of https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question?

Answer (score 0):

Ah ,I got another way to do it

**Without considering the order they are chosen**

there are $\binom{10}{5} = 252$ ways to choose 5 balls out of 10

and $\binom{3}{2} = 3$ ways to choose with odd-numbered draws and $\binom{5}{2} = 10$ ways to choose 2 balls out of 5 odd-numbered balls for each one of the previous three cases.

So the probability is $P(A) = \frac{3.10}{252} = \frac{5}{42}$